# INSERT new row by using sum of existing rows from same table

Tags: sql, sum, sql-insert

I'm writing a SQL script and I have this table

[image: So I have this table]

And I want to update the table inserting a new row with this result

[image: and I want to update the table inserting a new row with this result]

Having this formula `EIGHT TYPE 1= SEVEN-(ONE+TWO+THREE+FOUR+FIVE+SIX) when TYPE = 1`

How can I achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your formula would produce -14.

Comment: amount column must show absolute values :)

Comment: Please don't use images for data - use formatted/tabular text. And please show us what you tried and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: ok! @DaleK thank you for the feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation in order to add up the SEVEN value as positive and the others as negatives:

```
insert into mytable (company, kpi, date, location, type, amount)
  select 
    2, 'EIGHT TYPE1', 202101, 1, null,
    sum(case when kpi = 'SEVEN' then amount else -amount end)
  from mytable
  where type = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select company, kpi, date, location, type, amount
from t
union all
select company, 'EIGHT', date, location, NULL as type,
       sum(case when kpi in ('ONE', . . . ) then amount
                when kpi in ('SEVEN') then -amount
           end)
from t
where type = 1
group by company, date, location
```